# Receiving error in changing the password using System.DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, directoryservices, change-password

I've a web service deployed on one of the servers which internally uses System.DirectoryServices to change password using following code :

```
            DirectoryEntry obDirectoryEntry = GetCurrentUserDirectoryEntry();
            obDirectoryEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { sOldPassword, newPassword });
            obDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();
            obDirectoryEntry.Close();
```

This web service is working fine when hit from a particular different domain, but fails with following error when hit from some other :

**Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied.**

What could be the reason of this? And what is the workaround?

Thanks a lot,
Ishan

Answer (score 0):

Need more info about the particular network setup, but a workaround would be to specify the DomainController that works.

In your `GetCurrentUserDirectoryEntry()` method, you can use the overload:

```
var user = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://WorkingDomainController", ...);
```

See: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#7

Comment: Thanks. The tip that you gave for DirectoryEntry() is being done anyway but does not seem to be helping. Is there anything else that we're doing wrong? Any checklist for the network setup that can be referred to? Thanks again.

Comment: Just the basic stuff, verify that you can query LDAP/AD from powershell on the application machine and that the trust relationship between the machine and the domain is intact in the catalogs on both DCs. But really need more information on the AD setup - could be anything from site segmentation, to subnets, or anything...